# Rails / Rack default network timeout value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm investigating a system where I have a Rails app that talks to a Tomcat backend, and I'm seeing many "500 Connection reset by peer" errors.

I'd like to know what the timeout value is for Rails network requests.

Alternatively, where can I find this information? (Googling hasn't helped)

Comment: The answer might depend on how you do your network requests. Can you add some example code or explain what libraries or modules you use?

Comment: Aren't timeouts normally handled by the server?